# Java Spring Reactive - RabbitMQ Listener ReplyTo/Exchange Exception

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, reactive-programming

I've been trying to setup a reactive rabbitmq listener following the guidelines on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-amqp-reactive. 
What I'm hoping for my code to do is

- receive a message (works so far)
- do a whole bunch of logic that ultimately returns a Flux response (ie. async calls to endpoints and dbs)
- return the Flux as shown in the guide

When I attempt to run through the process with a sample event, I receive the following exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1651)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1555)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.ReplyFailureException: Failed to send reply with payload 'InvocationResult [returnValue=FluxSwitchIfEmpty, returnType=null]'
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.doHandleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:385)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:339)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:302)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:294)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: Cannot determine ReplyTo message property value: Request message does not contain reply-to property, and no default response Exchange was set.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.getReplyToAddress(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:465)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.doHandleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:381)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

From the message it looks like the problem stems from the published message not having a 'ReplyTo' property for specifying where the returned Flux should go to. This property is something that I will not be able to add. I've tried configuring a default exchange but nothing I've done seems to be working there. The code thats applicable is:

Configuration

```
    @Bean
    MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter() {

            @Override
            public Object fromMessage(Message message, Object conversionHint) throws MessageConversionException {

                message.getMessageProperties().setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);

                return super.fromMessage(message, conversionHint);
            }
        };

        messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper());

        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultClassMapper classMapper() {
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        classMapper.setDefaultType(NotificationEvent.class);
        return classMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(ReactiveNotificationController notificationHandler) {
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(notificationHandler, messageConverter());
        messageListenerAdapter.setDefaultListenerMethod("receive");
        return messageListenerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory rabbitListenerConnectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(rabbitListenerConnectionFactory);
        container.setQueues(queue());
        container.setReceiveTimeout(2000);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
        arguments.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", deadLetterQueueBaseName);
        arguments.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", deadLetterQueueBaseName);
        return new Queue(queueName, true, false, false, arguments);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(queueName, true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    Declarables declarables() {
        return new Declarables(new ArrayList<>(bindings()));
    }

    @Bean
    List<Binding> bindings() {
        List<Binding> bindings = new ArrayList<>();

        //Have the notification queue listen on both the deadLetterQueue routing key as well as the base one
        bindings.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange()).with(deadLetterQueueBaseName));
        bindings.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange()).with(""));

        //bind parent exchanges to our child exchange
        for (String parentExchangeName : parentExchangeNames) {
            FanoutExchange thisExchange = new FanoutExchange(parentExchangeName);
            bindings.add(BindingBuilder.bind(exchange()).to(thisExchange));
        }
        return bindings;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitProperties rabbitProperties(AmqpAdmin rabbitAdmin, AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return new RabbitProperties(rabbitAdmin, rabbitTemplate, deadLetterQueueBaseName, exchange(), baseTimeToLive);
    }
```

Receiver Controller

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class ReactiveNotificationController {

    private RabbitProperties rabbitProperties;

    private EventSubscriptionService subscriptionService;

    private NotificationSenderFactory senderFactory;

    @Value("${kibo.rabbitmq.queueName}")
    private String  queueName;

    public ReactiveNotificationController(RabbitProperties rabbitProperties,
                                          EventSubscriptionService subscriptionService,
                                          NotificationSenderFactory senderFactory) {
        this.rabbitProperties = rabbitProperties;
        this.subscriptionService = subscriptionService;
        this.senderFactory = senderFactory;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/queue/{queueName}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    @SendTo("{queueName}")
    public Flux<?> receive(NotificationEvent event) {
        NotificationWorker worker = new NotificationWorker(event, rabbitProperties, subscriptionService, senderFactory);
        return worker.run();
    }
}
```

The error still exists if I force the receive method to just return a Flux.empty() value so I don't think the worker has anything to do with it. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just set a reply-to then.

Comment: The service that will be publishing these messages won't be able to add a reply-to to the message; hence I'm not adding it for my test messages. That is unless you're implying something else that I'm missing.